# How do I hide my Groups on Facebook?

Tags: privacy, facebook-groups, facebook-profile

How do I hide my Groups on Facebook? The options seemed to have changed and now my groups are visible to my friends. I don't like losing friendships over Group memberships.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151548197721624

Answer (score 3):

You can click on `Edit Sections` (as explained in [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/511510208916469#How-do-I-unhide-or-hide-sections-%28ex%3a-Movies,-Music,-TV,-Books%29-on-my-About-page?-)) and unclick the `Groups` item in order to hide it from your `About` section.

However, as stated in that `Edit Sections` area:

> If you hide a section, individual stories can still appear on your timeline, in News Feed and elsewhere on Facebook.

It seems that it is not possible to *totally* hide your Groups information from *all* areas of Facebook.