# How can I keep my Facebook group membership private?

Tags: facebook, privacy

How can I make it so that people who aren't my friends on Facebook can't see which groups I'm in?

This is similar to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30854/how-do-i-hide-my-groups-on-facebook), but not quite.  The linked question asks about keeping things private from my friends, while my question is about keeping things private from strangers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Facebook's Help Community for [this answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151339922366780).

Normally, when viewing somebody's Profile, choosing "More >> Groups" will show the Open groups to which that person belongs.  However, by editing the `Group` section of your Profile (via the pencil icon):
[image]

... and then clicking `Edit Sections`:
[image]

... one can choose which sections show up in the Profile, and which will not:
[image]

Unchecking the `Groups` item will prevent it from being displayed in your Profile.
Note, however, that individual stories relating to a Group can still appear on your Timeline, in News Feed, or elsewhere on Facebook!

Answer (score 1):

Open Groups (Public) will always be able to be seen by strangers (non FB friends viewing your profile) as well as your friends.

This will help you more:
https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465